# Grab link to html textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, protocols

I have this link - http://am3yar0ra.in/test.html?a=52.472565,13.457407,Name

Now what i need is to read my test.html file and add the **a=52.472565,13.457407,Name** into a textbox and update the values automatically.

So that it can detect the URL protocol by following **Click Me!!** in test.html

---

Sorry for my bad english. Would be a great help.

```
<center><font size="40"><b>Test</b></font></center>


<br><br><br>

<a href="test://Name/52.472565,13.457407">Click Me!!</a><br>

<br>Mouse Over Select Name: <b></b>
<br><input type="text" style="height:20px;line-height:10px;color:green;" onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" size="25" value="Name" readonly="">

<br>Mouse Over Select Lat &amp; Lon: <b></b>
<br><input type="text" style="height:20px;line-height:10px;color:green;" onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" size="25" value="52.472565,13.457407" readonly="">

<br>Mouse over to Select Data: <b></b>
<br><input type="text" style="height:20px;line-height:10px;color:green;" onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" size="45" value="test://Name/52.472565,13.457407" readonly="">
```

Found the answer to what i was looking for. Did it in PHP though..

```
<?php
$location = $_GET['a'];
$locationSplit = explode(",", $location);
$lat = $locationSplit[0];
$lng = $locationSplit[1];
$name = $locationSplit[2];
$fullLocation = $lat.",". $lng;
// if latitude is between -90 / -180 <= lat / lng <= 90 / 180
// if (those checks are false)
//     die(0)
?>
```

Comment: You want to update input fields based on `test.html?a=52.472565,13.457407,Name` or you want to update the url based on the input fields ?

Comment: I want to update the text fields with the data url has.

Comment: I actually fount the answer myself. I just had to split the data and add the values in a text field. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: Great that you figured it out, consider posting the answer, someone else might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setInterval(change,1000/30);
function change() {
  var x = document.getElementById('change');
  x.setAttribute("onclick","location.href='test://Name/52.472565,13.457407'");
}
```

Comment: That did not help